# Saving a Pandas DataFrame to a JSON string

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I realize that this may seem like a question that has already been asked here, but none of the solutions seem to work. I start out with a dictionary that looks something along the line of this:

`{'2016-05-08': 1, '2016-05-09': nan, '2016-05-05': nan, '2016-05-06': nan, '2016-05-07': nan, '2016-05-11': nan, 'address': '<email address>, '2016-05-12': nan, '2016-05-10': nan}`

I read this data into a pandas DataFrame, looking something like this:

`address    date1    date2    date3    date4    date5   date6    date7
<email>      NaN      NaN      NaN       1       NaN     NaN      NaN`

I then use the following methods to calculate the mean and standard deviation and add them to the DataFrame:

`mean = pd.Series(df.mean(axis=1), index=df.index)
std = pd.Series(df.std(axis=1), index=df.index)
df = pd.concat([df, mean, std], axis=1)`

When I `print df`, it looks as it should. However, when I used this method to write the DataFrame to a JSON string, `df.to_json(<path to file>)`, it get the original dictionary in my JSON file. I want a JSON string of all the data with the standard deviation and mean included in the JSON data, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

If your summary columns give you the data you expect, add the columns to the dataframe.

Try

```
df['std'] = pd.Series(df.std(axis=1), index=df.index)

df['mean'] = pd.Series(df.mean(axis=1), index=df.index)
```

Then export to JSON.

Edit:  ok, I see that you see it works with print df now sorry).

I was unable to reproduce your results. this is what I have:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'2016-05-08': 1, '2016-05-09': float('nan'), '2016-05-05': float('nan'), '2016-05-06': float('nan'), '2016-05-07': float('nan'), '2016-05-11': float('nan'), 'address': '<email address>', '2016-05-12': float('nan'), '2016-05-10': float('nan')}

df = pd.DataFrame(d, index=[0])

mean = pd.Series(df.mean(axis=1), index=df.index)
std = pd.Series(df.std(axis=1), index=df.index)
df = pd.concat([df, mean, std], axis=1)

df.to_json('correctoutput.txt')
```

Here is the json with the output:

http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=c0b29191d89fba8b593e29009af4f382

Comment: Isn't that what the `concat` method does?

Comment: Doesn't change output

Comment: @GrantSteiner, aside from the above edit, try this df.to_json() without the file to see if you get the right output.

Comment: Figured it out. It was an issue with other code in the program. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @grant steiner glad I could help.  Marking this as the answer would be appreciated.